# Asp.net Core IFormFile type Migration fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I want to add the picture to the Class, but asp.net Core migration failed:

**error message:**
The property `Product.ImageFile` is of an interface type (`IFormFile`). If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property from the model.

**product.cs:**

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
[FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png,jpeg,bmp")]
public IFormFile ImageFile { set; get; }
```

And how should I store the pictures?

Comment: Up voting for not providing evidence for voting down. Down Voting without proper explanation is not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said, you cannot store an interface directly with Entity Framework, you have to give an actual implementation type.

If you debug and stop in your controller you can see that the actual type you receive is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile` so if you want to save it you should use this type instead.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
[....]
[....]
public FormFile ImageFile { set; get; }
```

But anyway you **cannot** save this directly to your database. First reason is because the data is accessible through a stream given by a method of this object, not directly from a property. Entity Framework doesn't know how to perform that, it can only save properties' values.

```
byte[] data;
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
}
```

Now why do you want to save your file directly in your Database? I suggest you instead to save the file somewhere on your hard drive and keep its path in your DB.

```
var filePath = myPhisicalOrRelativePath + "/" + file.FileName; //Be careful with duplicate file names
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Your Product model will contain a property

```
public string FilePath {get; set;}
```

Then you have to set your property `FilePath` in your `Product` object with your `filePath` variable

```
myProduct.FilePath = filePath;
```

If you really want to store the data directly in you database and not as a physical file, I suggest you could add the properties you need in your `Product` model instead of saving a `FormFile` directly.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

//using variables of the previous code examples
myProduct.FileData = data;
myProduct.FileName = file.FileName;
```